# Cordova - Push notification behavior while app is on background mode

Tags: android, cordova, notifications

I'm working on push notifications for Android and everything is working pretty good.

When app is open and active or closed, push notifications are working as expected.

When app is open but working on background - the push notification is received, but there are two possible outcomes here:

1. The notification is pressed on the top taskbar - works as expected -> awakens the app from sleep mode and gets the notification.
2. The app is being opened by the icon and not from the taskbar, the notification remains on the taskbar, and no events are being fired.

It would be expected that the notification will be removed when the app opens from on background, but it just stays there on top. And when clicked, the notification disappears and no data is received from it.

I wonder how you clever guys have solved it? I heard of the cordova background mode plugin, but I'm not sure whether it's the right solution to jump right into it. I guess I could get the data from the server instead, but what about removing the notification from the taskbar?

Much thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to manage all the notification things by yourself. That means: After the app comes to the front (resume), you have to remove the notification. Otherwise it will stay there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so do you mean it's up to the user to remove the notifications? Or is there a way to remove the notification from the taskbar? It seems like it doesn't get removed unless clicked or cleared in Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble, so I found out about this `'resume'` event from cordova, that actually gets called whenever the app is coming from background mode.

That is just the functionality I was looking for. Maybe it'll help someone someday. ;)